# TFS + Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, tfs, azure-devops, runner

I have a project on local TFS server. This project has a PowerShell script which creates the build.

I need to create a correct JOB in Jenkins, which will start when any change happens in the project (TFS). This job will automatically start PS script on project directory.

Please, help me with this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you just need to integrate Jenkins with TFS and set CI/CD to trigger the build/release in Jenkins.

To run PowerShell in Jenkins you can refer this article: [Running Powershell scripts using Jenkins](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/running-powershell-scripts-using-jenkins/)

For the Jenkins integration and CI/CD, you can reference below articles:

- [TFS and Jenkins Integration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/12/31/tfs-and-jenkins-integration/)
- [Visual Studio Team Services Integration with Jenkins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/25/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/)
- [Tutorial: Integrate your Jenkins CI jobs with VSTS CD to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/integrate-jenkins-vsts-cicd?view=vsts)